# Изменение view-компонента listView через onItemClick

Tags: java, android

Меня интересует, как изменить *TextView* из пункта в *ListView*, через метод *OnItemClick*.

Части кода ниже:

```
listView.setAdapter(new VivzAdapter(this));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        //?///////////////////////?//
        }
    }
});

class SingleRow{
    String title;
    SingleRow(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}


class VivzAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
VivzAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String[]titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.title);
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i]));
    }
}


 @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewGroup,false);
    TextView title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);

    SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

    title.setText(temp.title);

    return row;
}
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы работать с данными адаптера за пределами адаптера (в активити), эти данные должны формироваться в самой активити и передаваться в адаптер в готовом виде, а не заполнятся внутри самого адаптера - это вообще не самое лучшее решение. Затем вы манипулируете этими данными, как считаете нужным и делаете адаптеру `notifyDataSetChanged()` - обновить вьюшки, так как данные изменились.

Comment: Пожалуйста подскажите, как сделать это правильно.Т.к у меня не получилось: я присваивал стринг-полям стринг-ресурсы, а потом в масив добавлял ети поля.

Comment: Изменения должны сохранятся при перезапуске приложения ? Данные у вас - массив из элементов с одной строкой ? Зачем тогда так сложно все. Класс-модель, переопределение адаптера, да еще и `BaseAdapter` ... Перепишите вопрос, как делали то, что не получалось. Это совсем не правильно все.

Answer (score 1):

Может проще сделать свой "кастомный" `ListView` в виде массива `TextView` внутри вертикального `ScrollView`? Тогда обращаемся к каждому из этих `TextView` как к объекту в массиве и меняем ему вид как хочется. Правда, придется им данные тоже "вручную" подсовывать.